# How to solve evolution equation numerically?

Tags: solid-mechanics, computational-mechanics

How do I solve the following evolution equation numerically:

$$
\dot{\boldsymbol{\mathcal A}} = -\lambda A_1|\boldsymbol{s}-\boldsymbol{\alpha}|^2\left[(\boldsymbol{n}_r:\boldsymbol{\alpha})\boldsymbol{n}_r\otimes\boldsymbol{n}_r+\frac{3}{2}A_2\boldsymbol{\mathcal A}\right]
$$

Here $\boldsymbol{\mathcal A}$ is a fourth-order tensor, $\boldsymbol{s}$ is the deviatoric stress, $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ is the back stress, and $\boldsymbol{n}_r$ is $\frac{\boldsymbol{s}-\boldsymbol{\alpha}}{|\boldsymbol{s}-\boldsymbol{\alpha}|}$. $A_1, A_2$ are material constants, and $\lambda$ is a parameter that is dependent on $\boldsymbol{s},\boldsymbol{\alpha},\boldsymbol{\mathcal A}$.

This is the evolution equation from the paper ["Directional distortional hardening in metal plasticity within thermodynamics"](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijsolstr.2007.04.025), where they got this equation from Clausius-Dirhem inequality.

Comment: You could try what they say in the paper: "To fit these experiments, the model was implemented numerically using the procedure outlined by Bardet and Choucair (1991) which essentially takes loading increments of stress, strain, or combinations of the two and converts them into increments of stress only. Using this procedure, the numerical loading conditions are designed to exactly match those from the experiment, and each increment of load is converted into stress increments. Once the stress increment is obtained, incremental changes to strain and internal variables are calculated using..."

Comment: Separately, though, the equation is just an ODE. There is plenty of software to solve ODEs out there.